# Selenium: Scrape Images from EBay Listing

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to scrape images from `EBay` listing using `Selenium`.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
driver.get("http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPhone-5s-16gb-Factory-GSM-Unlocked-Smartphone-B/131354612531?hash=item1e95585333");
String xpath = ".//div[@id='PicturePanel']";
List<WebElement> srcs;
srcs = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));

for(WebElement src : srcs) {
   System.out.println(src.getAttribute("src"));
}
```

But it does not return anything.

How can I scrape all images of this listing ?

Comment: Use their API instead. Much easier and more stable.

Answer (score 0):

With that XPath, you requested a DIV with an ID PicturePanel and I'm sure that's what you got.

```
<div id="PicturePanel" class="pp-c">
```

The problem is that you are looping through a collection of 1 element (the DIV) and it's not a picture so it doesn't have a src attribute. You need to get the IMG tags that are descendants of that tag and *then* get their src.